# woocommerce Archive filtering, combine attributes (colors)

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, attributes

I'm trying to set up a color filter for a woocommerce site where the owner has set the color attributes to colors like "Harbo Green Melange", "Horizon Blue" and "Ketchup".

How can I combine attributes so that "Sugar Coral Melange", "Red Chili Mix" and "Ketchup" can be added under the filter option "Red"?

Anyone know of a filter plugin where this is posible, or can push me in the right direction of how to build this myself.

Thanks! :)

Thanks